# SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry

Is the registry tree structure for SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION automatically created when IE is installed?

Comment: which IE? given it's a core component of windows which microsoft claims can't be removed without causing the universe to implode, it'd come to down to which version of IE introduced that registry setting.

Comment: Undocumented, hence subject to change.  Whatever the answer is, don't depend on it for anything important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the registry entry is included as part of IE installation.

It was first introduced back in IE8 as part of an extensibility improvement:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx